# Why not displayed in the console, a group of links to resources Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri

**Why not displayed in the console, a group of links to resources Ruby**

```
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=ruby'

open(url) { |page| page_content = page.read()
links = page_content.scan(/<a class=1.*?href=\"(.*?)\"/).flatten
links.each { |link| puts link }
}
```

**Console output blank line**

```
E:\work\storeapp3\app\storeapp\shop>ruby robota_z_fail.rb
```

**Where am I wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in regexp:

```
#         ⇓
/<a class=1.*?href=\"(.*?)\"/
```

Remove `1` and enjoy.